# Is there a formula or VBA method to determine which cell is highlighted in Excel?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I want to write a formula that gets the row and column number of the cell that the user has clicked on. Every time the user clicks a different cell, the formula should automatically update to reflect the currently selected cell. I'm guessing that this can't be done by formula - if not, is there a way to do it in VBA?

Comment: What cell is this formula supposed to be in? Sounds doable with the [`SelectionChange`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.selectionchange) event.

Comment: It can be in any cell, for example A1. Thanks - is that an event in the sense that the subroutine will run every time you click a different cell?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what it is designed to do.

Comment: Okay, cool. I've never actually written VBA code before, do you know how I would read the currently selected cell and output it within that subroutine?

Comment: The currently selected cell(s) would be `Target` - see the docs link.

Comment: Okay, I'll have a tinker in a bit, post some code and see where I get to. Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The closest solution you can come to using a formula is the `CELL` function:

**Row number**

```
=ROW(INDIRECT(CELL("address")))
```

**Column number**

```
=COLUMN(INDIRECT(CELL("address")))
```

The `=CELL("address")` function will give you the address string of the cell. So in order to put that string into the `COLUMN` or `ROW` function, you need the INDIRECT function as well.

Be aware that this formula will calculate **after** the user has made a change to the selected cell.

Comment: Thank you for this excellent answer, I have learned something new. Something I noticed though, it does calculate (in excel 2016) without any change made to the cell. It just takes a fair few seconds.

Comment: @Plutian Thanks for your kind comment :-). I just checked that in Office 365. Just changing the selection of the cell does not recalculate the formula for me. However, if I change the selection (single click) and then click on "Calculate now", the formula will also recalculate.

Comment: It won't recalculate just selecting a cell, > Select a cell > `F2` > `Enter` =)

Comment: This might have to do with the version, but also with the calculation intensity. It seems to be a heavy calculation, especially if I use multiples of this statement on the same sheet it stops calculating automatically, and spikes the CPU quite a bit when clicking "calculate".

Comment: Whoa, this is a super cool formula! This will probably do fine for my purposes, although it's useful to know about the VBA solutions as well!

Answer (score 5):

For a cross between a formula and a selection-change approach:

Start by creating a 1-cell named range called `Selection`

In the worksheet code module add:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    ActiveWorkbook.Names("Selection").RefersTo = Target
End Sub
```

Then in a cell add a formula like:

```
=ADDRESS(ROW(Selection),COLUMN(Selection))
```

The selection change will update the reference of the named range, and then the formula takes care of the rest. The advantage of this approach rather than simply the selection change is that the formula can be freely moved around and copied without having to modify the selection change code.

Comment: What a nice solution - I have to admit that I even prefer it over my own, formula based solution ;-). Another advantage of your solution is that the formula already recalculates on selection change. So if a macro activated workbook is not a problem, I would prefer that one.

Comment: Very clever! =)

Answer (score 2):

[This is possible with formula's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59375525/11936678), but relatively easier and quicker with VBA. The [`SelectionChange`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.selectionchange) event is designed exactly for this.

Here is a short example that will show a message box with which cell you have clicked.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
MsgBox "You clicked cell: " & Target.Address
End Sub
```

You could also use this  to adapt a formula:

```
Sheet1.Range("A1").Formula = "=5+" & Target.Value
```

In this example if the cell you clicked holds "5", cell A1 will show "10" as a result of this formula: "=5+5"

Comment: It is possible with formulas, nonetheless, this is the prefered method as far as Im concerned +

Comment: @JvdV You have me intrigued, how would I refer to the currently active cell with a formula?

Comment: @MichaelWycisk has got that covered :)